# How to check whether a SQL query is successful with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to C# and SQL. Now from a form I access a function in a class.

My code is

```
public void updateSupplierInformation(string id, string name, string balance, string place, string address, string phone, string bankname, string bankbranch, string accountno)
{
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand NewCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        NewCmd.Connection = conn;
        NewCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        NewCmd.CommandText = " update supplier set " + " ID = " + "'" + id + "'" + " , NAME = " + "'" + name + "'" + " , BALANCE = " + "'" + balance + "'" + " , PLACE = " + "'" + place + "'" + "  , LOCATION = " + "'" + address + "'" + ",  PHONE = " + "'" + phone + "'" + " , BANK_NAME = " + "'" + bankname + "'" + " , BANK_BRANCH = " + "'" + bankbranch + "'" + ", ACCOUNT_NO = " + "'" + accountno + "'" + " where ID = " + "@id";
        NewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
        NewCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Now if a record doesn't exist in the database with the given `id` the application stops immediately. How can I handle this? I want to show a message that the data entered is wrong and ask the user to enter another data

Comment: Don't try to update records that don't exist?

Comment: why is that only the last ID is parameterized?

Comment: By the way - this is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you really should be parameterizing _all_ fields.

Comment: can u tell me how to parametrise all fields

Comment: @aravindbharathy a simple explanation of parameterized queries [here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06).

Comment: Why are you trying to update the ID field?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery() returns number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.If you need to check sql exception you have to include a try catch statement in your function.

```
public void updateSupplierInformation(string id, string name, string balance, string place, string address, string phone, string bankname, string bankbranch, string accountno)
    {
       try
       {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand NewCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        NewCmd.Connection = conn;
        NewCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        NewCmd.CommandText = " update supplier set " + " ID = " + "'" + id + "'" + " , NAME = " + "'" + name + "'" + " , BALANCE = " + "'" + balance + "'" + " , PLACE = " + "'" + place + "'" + "  , LOCATION = " + "'" + address + "'" + ",  PHONE = " + "'" + phone + "'" + " , BANK_NAME = " + "'" + bankname + "'" + " , BANK_BRANCH = " + "'" + bankbranch + "'" + ", ACCOUNT_NO = " + "'" + accountno + "'" + " where ID = " + "@id";
        NewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
        int a=NewCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        conn.Close();
        if(a==0)
          //Not updated.
        else
          //Updated.
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
         {
         // Not updated
         }
    }
```

Comment: It's a really bad idea to just catch `Exception`, other than at the top level. You should catch *specific* exceptions. Also, the code you've given still doesn't reliably dispose of the command, and it's still using SQL-injection-vulnerable parameter handling. Basically, it's still awful code.

Comment: What is in case of a DDL query.

Answer (score 23):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected - if it's 0, that means there were no matching rows to update. Of course, that's only if the update actually "works" in terms of not throwing an exception... whereas I suspect it's throwing an exception in your case, which probably *isn't* to do with the row not existing in the database. (It's possible that there's some code you haven't shown which *does* depend on the row existing, mind you.)

Additionally:

- You should use parameterized SQL for *all* parameters rather than including the values directly in your SQL.
- You should use `using` statements to dispose of resources reliably.
- It looks like you're using a single connection - don't do that. Create (and dispose via `using`) a new connection each time you want to perform a database operation, and let the connection pool handle the efficiency
- Work out why the application is just stopping. An exception is almost certainly being thrown, and it's really important that when that happens, you get the details of the exception. You *may* want to catch it and keep going (at some high level) depending on the exact context... but you should always at least end up logging it.

My *guess* (on a casual inspection) is that the problem is that your update statement tries to update the ID, which would presumably be read-only. But you'll find that out when you fix your exception handling.

Comment: I think OP means that the SQL exception causes the process to terminate.

Comment: can u tell how to parametrise all fields and how to use 'using'

Comment: @Oded: Yes, I suspect so too - hence the last bullet point of my edit. But the first part addresses the title of the question.

Comment: @aravindbharathy: Well you're already using *one* parameter - but only one. You should do some research - both parameterized SQL and `using` statements are handled extensively on the web. Please read my edited answer for more suggestions.

Comment: can we use `SqlConnection.InfoMessage`) to see the result in C# application **or** save the result in `txt` file, just to know if the script was successfully executed , because recently using `sqlcmd` when i executed 150 mb script file on remote host,  after 55 minutes some rows were effected with this error, `TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` , `communication link failure`. ,  no of rows effected can be known , but i am concerned about error messages while running database generated script file.

Answer (score 2):

Check the condition

```
int a=NewCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    if(a==0)
      //Not updated.
    else
      //Updated.
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is already an answer posted but let`s try something else:

```
SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection("datahere");
SqlCommand SQLComm = new SqlCommand();
SQLcomm.Connection = SQLConn;
SQLConn.Open();
SQLComm.CommandText = "SQL statement goes here"
SqlDataReader dataReader = SQLComm.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
if(dataReader.HasRows == true){ //if it has rows do code
//do code
}
else{
// do other code
}
```

HasRows will return a bool value

Comment: What if this was a plain update statement in a SP to check if the SQL did not break ?

Comment: Just use Entity Framework and Linq :D it will handle all of this more elegantly